# How to represent variables that are "mutually different" in proposition logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

For example, how can I rewrite $$\forall a\exists b\exists c\exists d\forall e\left({a\ne b\wedge a\ne c\wedge a\ne d\wedge b\ne c\wedge b\ne d\wedge c\ne d\wedge P\left({e,a}\right)}\right)$$ into a simpler form, where I just want to show that $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are **mutually/pairwise different**?

I think one way is to write $$\forall a\exists b\exists c\exists d\forall e\left({\left|{\left\{{a,b,c,d}\right\}}\right|=4\wedge P\left({e,a}\right)}\right),$$ but I wonder if it's *legit* to use notations from set theory in propositional logic, and if there are any other ways.

Comment: No.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language you are using has $\neq$ as a symbol (a lot of texts use only $=$ and you have to write $\lnot(a=b)$ instead of $a \neq b$) then AFAIK the only way to stay within logic and your language is indeed to assert an explicit $a \neq b$ for every unordered pairs $\{a,b\}$, so for $4$ variables we need $\binom{4}{2}=6$ such statements in conjunction (so with $\land$ between them), as you have done.

If you're allowed to do so, you could introduce a new $4$-ary predicate by an abbreviation, so e.g. $$ D(x,y,z,u) := \lnot(x = y) \land \lnot(x = z) \land \lnot(x = u) \land \lnot(y = z) \land \lnot(y = u) \land \lnot(u = v) $$
(using the strict interpretation) and then writing your statement as

$$\forall a\exists b\exists c\exists d\forall e: D(a,b,c,d) \land P(e,a)$$

if brevity is what you're after.

Comment: Well, we still need to write the long conjunction this way, but I have a new idea now: We can replace $(a, b, c, d)$ with $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ and rewrite it as $$\bigwedge_{i\ne j}{x_i\ne x_j},$$ can't we?

Comment: @MinutesSneezer that’s a mixture of metalanguage and the language you’re using because you’re using the indexes of the variables. It’s sometimes done, but it’s not “pure” either.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the concept of *metalanguage* is. Is it not allowed to index variables? Regardless of its impurity, though, I just take $\bigwedge$ as a symbol to simplify conjunctions just like the case where mathematicians commonly use $\sum$ to simplify additions. It at least saves us the trouble of listing all the $\binom{n}{2}$ statements.

Comment: @MinutesSneezer like I said, you can do it, but it depends on what the purpose of the formula is. If you’re doing proof theory and induction on structure of formulas etc. You have to be “pure”.  Just as a more formal way of writing the statement, ok, or do use extra notions like cardinality.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for that detailed explanation. :)